# List of lists weird python issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

```
list= []

x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

for i in range(2):

          list.append(x)

list[0][0]="x"

print list
```

And after printing I get this:

```
[['x', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['x', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']]
```

The first item in every list was replaced by 'x' whereas I only wanted the first item in the first list to be replaced by 'x'(hence the line list[0][0]="x")

Comment: This has gotta be a dupe

Comment: You add the same list twice to another list: `list.append(x)`. You then change that list. There is only one unique list object in your list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

The line `list.append(x)` adds a reference to `x` into `list`. Both sublists end up pointing to the same object (as does `x`). In fact, doing `x[0] = 'x'` would have the exact same effect as `list[0][0] = 'x'`. To make the sub-lists independent, make a copy by doing `list.append(x.copy())` or `list.append(x[:])`